# Drag and drop an to TextBox in a specific mouse position - Show caret or position indicator

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, drag-and-drop, treeview

I am pasting an item from a `TreeView` to a `TextBox`, but I want to paste that item in the mouse's current position and also show a caret like the image below.
Image with caret:
[image: example]

Here is my code:

```
private void tvOperador_ItemDrag(object sender, ItemDragEventArgs e)
{
    var node = (TreeNode)e.Item;
    if (node.Level > 0)
    {
        DoDragDrop(node.Text, DragDropEffects.Copy);
    }
}
private void txtExpresion_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(string))) e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
}
private void txtExpresion_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(System.String)))
    {
        string Item = (System.String)e.Data.GetData(typeof(System.String));
        string[] split = Item.Split(':');

        txtExpresion.Text += split[1];
    }
}
```

Comment: See the updated answer, which merges the best of my original and of @Reza's solution!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is tricky as the `Drag&Drop` operation keeps the mouse **captured**, so you can't use the mouse events..

One way is to set up a `Timer` to do the work..:

```
    Timer cursTimer = new Timer();

    void cursTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int cp = txtExpresion.GetCharIndexFromPosition(
                 txtExpresion.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition));
        txtExpresion.SelectionStart = cp;
        txtExpresion.SelectionLength = 0; 
        txtExpresion.Refresh();
    }
```

The `Timer` uses the `Control.MousePosition` function to determined the cursor position every 25ms or so, sets the caret and updates the `TextBox`.

In your events you initialize it and make sure the `TextBox` has focus; finally you add the string at the current selection:

```
    private void txtExpresion_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(string)))
        {
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
            txtExpresion.Focus();
            cursTimer = new Timer();
            cursTimer.Interval = 25;
            cursTimer.Tick += cursTimer_Tick;
            cursTimer.Start();
        }
    }

    private void txtExpresion_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(System.String)))
        {
            cursTimer.Stop();

            string Item = (System.String)e.Data.GetData(typeof(System.String));
            string[] split = Item.Split(':');

            txtExpresion.SelectedText = split[1]
        }
    }
```

A different way to solve it would be to not use normal Drag&Drop and only code the mouse events but this one worked ok a my first tests.

**Update**

While the above solution does work, using a `Timer` seems not exactly **elegant**. Much better to use the `DragOver` event, as seen in Reza's answer. But instead of painting a cursor, why not do the real thing, i.e. take control of the actual I-beam..?

The `DragOver` event is called all the time during the move so it works pretty much like `MousMove` would: So here is a merger of the two solutions, which I believe is the best way to do it:

```
private void txtExpresion_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(System.String)))
    {
        string Item = (System.String)e.Data.GetData(typeof(System.String));
        string[] split = Item.Split(':');
        txtExpresion.SelectionLength = 0;
        txtExpresion.SelectedText = split[1];
    }
}

private void txtExpresion_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(string)))
    {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
        txtExpresion.Focus();
    }
}

private void txtExpresion_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    int cp = txtExpresion.GetCharIndexFromPosition(
                          txtExpresion.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition));
    txtExpresion.SelectionStart = cp;
    txtExpresion.Refresh();

}
```

Comment: I like this solution.  I noticed that I couldn't move the cursor to _after_ the last character (as shown in the gif in Reza's answer).  I found a solution to this behavior online and it worked for me:

[C# .NET problem with drag & drop text onto textbox at caret](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8e90f032-31fa-4ab2-8cdd-61170835f91f/c-net-problem-with-drag-amp-drop-text-onto-textbox-at-caret?forum=csharpgeneral)

Answer (score 3):

You can draw a caret over `TextBox` in `DragOver` event. Also set the `SelectionStart` to the char index you get from mouse position. Then in `DragDrop` event, just set `SelectedText`.

[image]

```
private void textBox1_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(System.String)))
    {
        var position = textBox1.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
        var index = textBox1.GetCharIndexFromPosition(position);
        textBox1.SelectionStart = index;
        textBox1.SelectionLength = 0;
        textBox1.Refresh();
        using (var g = textBox1.CreateGraphics())
        {
            var p = textBox1.GetPositionFromCharIndex(index);
            g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, p.X, 0, p.X, textBox1.Height);
        }
    }
}

private void textBox1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(System.String)))
    {
        string txt = (System.String)e.Data.GetData(typeof(System.String));
        textBox1.SelectedText = txt;
    }
}
```

Comment: That is a very nice alternative! @Reza: Can you tell me what you used to make that animation?

Comment: @TaW Thanks for the feedback :) I used [ScreenToGif](https://screentogif.codeplex.com/). This tool allows you to record a selected area of your screen and save it as a Gif.

Comment: I see a dark shadow of the drop position indicator in the gif, but it does't exist in the `TextBox` when executing. It's just for the quality or sampling rate of the gif. It's completely clear at run-time.

Comment: Hm, I don't see the shadow. But then I'm asleep ;-)